# Python - Django - Test Models.save method

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Could anyone help me in find a solution to test the Models.save method from Django?
What I´m interested here is testing that a Model is beeing saved with all the arguments it needs.
It´s a "legacy" database, not managed by django manage.py module

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    myname = models.Charfield(max_length=10, null=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False

class MyModelTest(TestCase):

    def test_create_my_model_instance(self):
        my_model = Mock(autospec=MyModel)
        instance = my_model(randomarg=10)
        instance.save()
        # here i´d want to assert if instance has the
        # necessary arguments to save to db
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. How do you define the "necessary" arguments?

Comment: By necessary arguments i mean all the arguments declared in the Model Class

Comment: But why would you need to test that? Under what circumstances could that fail to be the case? Saving a model is part of Django's internals and is well tested by the existing Django test suite.

Comment: is `assert instance.randomarg == 10` somehow not enough?

Comment: If i refactor my model i want make sure i won´t brake my code by trying to save a Model with the wrong number of fields

Answer (score 0):

You want to test MyModel, but you're mocking it.  You should only mock something that you don't want tested (for example, mocking a call that makes an HTTP request that you'd rather avoid).

The test you've written would work aside from that.  Just call save, and then assert that the fields you've set have been saved.

Comment: I´m mocking MyModel bc i dont want to actually save it to the database, I just want to assert that it has all the fields i declared populaded, but i don´t know how to do that.

Comment: I've been down the "don't use the database for tests" road.  It produced tests of questionable value.

That being said, you should be able to instantiate your model without saving it to the db, as long as you don't call save - no mocking required.  Then, what you seem to want to do is make an assertion about the model's __ dict __ attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think that testing `save()` method without having it overriden is not recommended since it's a django stuff.. we shouldn't test saving and editing fields of models without having customized work when saving/editing.